# How to Repeat by Horizontal using GMAP.NET in C #?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

Is it possible to implement repetition of maps along the Y axis?
Now the map is displayed so:

[image: map screenshot]

Need:

[image: repeated Y axis screenshot]

Comment: Adding some code showing what you tried would be useful

Comment: ste-fu - Excuse me. I tried to repeat the picture on the Y axis. It did not work. I did this with the Two Rectangles intersection. I'll finish the code for the cards later.

Comment: At the moment there is no code.